# Feynman's rule for Green's function of particle in the external field and with interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, greens-functions

I'm learning the quantum field theory for condensed matter systems, and I've just learnt about the single particle Green's function with interaction and its Feynman rule. But I met some problems when I tried to add an external field into the Hamiltonian. I don't know how to use the Feynman rule in this Hamiltonian:

$$\begin{aligned}
H & =\int d^{3} x\psi ^{\dagger }( x)\left( -\frac{\hbar ^{2} \nabla ^{2}}{2m}\right) \psi ( x) +\int d^{3} x\psi ^{\dagger }( x) V_{r}( x) \psi ( x)\\
 & +\frac{1}{2}\int d^{3} x\int d^{3} yV_{int}( x-y) \psi ^{\dagger }( x) \psi ^{\dagger }( y) \psi ( y) \psi ( x)
\end{aligned}$$

the single particle Green's function is defined as

$$iG( x,t_x;x',t_{x'}) =\frac{{\langle\Phi _{0}}|T\left\{U( -\infty ,+\infty ) \psi _{I}( x,t_x) \psi _{I}^{\dagger }( x',t_{x'})\right\}|{\Phi _{0}}\rangle}{\langle\Phi _{0}| U( +\infty ,-\infty )|\Phi _{0}\rangle}$$

where the subscript $I$ denotes the operator in the interaction picture, and the unitary operator is defined as

$$U(t,t')=T\left\{\exp\big(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t'}^{t}dt^{''}H'_I(t^{''})\big)\right\}$$
with

$$H'_I(t)=e^{iH_0t/\hbar}H'e^{-iH_0t/\hbar}$$
$$H_0=\int d^{3} x\psi ^{\dagger }( x)\left( -\frac{\hbar ^{2} \nabla ^{2}}{2m}\right) \psi ( x)$$
$$H'=\int d^{3} x\psi ^{\dagger }( x) V_{r}( x) \psi ( x)+\frac{1}{2}\int d^{3} x\int d^{3} yV_{int}( x-y) \psi ^{\dagger }( x) \psi ^{\dagger }( y) \psi ( y) \psi ( x)$$

I only know how to write the Feynman rule without the external potential $V_r$. Can anyone help me with the Feynman rule for this Hamiltonian to $n$-th order of $V_r$ and $m$-th order of $V_{int}$?

Comment: You can modify your propagator so that you don't treat $V_r$ perturbatively by diagonalising the quadratic part. Alternatively, you add extra edges corresponding to $V_r$ kind of what you may have seen for counter terms.